# Parse JSON in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some data in a pandas DataFrame, but one of the columns contains multi-line JSON. I am trying to parse that JSON out into a separate DataFrame along with the CustomerId. Here you will see my DataFrame...

```
df

Out[1]: 
Id                                           object
CustomerId                                   object
CallInfo                                     object
```

Within the CallInfo column, the data looks like this...

```
[{"CallDate":"2021-06-21","CallLength":362},{"CallDate":"2021-06-24","CallLength":402}]
```

I want to create a new DataFrame called df_norm which contains the CustomerId, CallDate, and CallLength.

I have tried several ways but couldn't find a working solution. Can anyone help me with this?

Mock up code example...

```
import pandas as pd
import json

Id = [1, 2, 3]
CustomerId = [700001, 700002, 700003]
CallInfo = ['[{"CallDate":"2021-06-21","CallLength":362},{"CallDate":"2021-06-24","CallLength":402}]', '[{"CallDate":"2021-07-09","CallLength":102}]', '[{"CallDate":"2021-07-11","CallLength":226},{"CallDate":"2021-07-11","CallLength":216}]']

# Reconstruct sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Id": Id,
        "CustomerId": CustomerId,
        "CallInfo": CallInfo
    })

print(df)
```

Comment: @timgeb 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Create a new list of rows and then toss that into the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```py
new_rows = [{
    'Id': row['Id'],
    'CustomerId': row['CustomerId'],
    'CallDate': item['CallDate'],
    'CallLength': item['CallLength']} 
    for _, row in df.iterrows() for item in json.loads(row['CallInfo'])]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
print(new_df)
```

EDIT: to account for `None` values in `CallInfo` column:

```py
new_rows = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    call_date = None
    call_length = None
    if row['CallInfo'] is not None: # Or additional checks, e.g. == "" or something...
        for item in json.loads(row['CallInfo']):
            call_date = item['CallDate']
            call_length = item['CallLength']

    new_rows.append({
        'Id': row['Id'],
        'CustomerId': row['CustomerId'],
        'CallDate': call_date,
        'CallLength': call_length})
```

Comment: Almost there I think, this works on my mockup, but on the real data I'm getting "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType"

Comment: Ah, then you must have a few `None` values in the rows of the `CallInfo` column which you should check for. I'll edit the answer to account for this

Comment: @g8iyzsoo4 Please upvote and/or accept my answer if it is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Legend!! Thanks!!